# Why are some websites seemingly immune to self-signed certificate MitM attacks?

Tags: tls, certificates, man-in-the-middle, certificate-authority, account-security

I recently did an experiment using MitM to gain account information (username and password) while accessing websites. I used two PCs in the scenario; one as the target, running Internet Explorer, and one as the attacker, running ettercap. One attempt (pretending to be steamcommunity.com) yielded information; the target accepted the attacker's fake CA self-signed certificate presented via the MitM attack. The other attempt (pretending to be facebook.com) didn't even allow me to add an exception for the self-signed certificate on the target machine. So the question is, why did one website allow me to add an exception while the other one didn't?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Facebook uses HSTS (with preload[*]) while steamcommunity.com doesn't.

[HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is a HTTP header that has two effects:

1. It forces all connections to the site over HTTPS (even if it was accidentally linked/bookmarked/typed as HTTP)
2. It aborts if any HTTPS error or warning exists. This includes self-signed certificate warnings, which means that it is impossible to accept these certificates.

<sub>[*] preload means that the browser is aware of HSTS even before the first visit. Without preload, you could perform a man in the middle attack on the very first request to the site, even if HSTS exists.</sub>

Comment: It may be important to explain that 'preload' means that the browser is aware of the site using HSTS, even before first communication. So in those cases you can't even exploit the first transaction to the site to perform a downgrade attack.

Comment: @MiaoHatola good point, I added it

Comment: Does preloading mean there's literally a hardcoded list of sites inside my browser's install binary?  If so, are those lists coordinated anywhere between vendors?  What if I wanted to get my site onto that list?

Comment: @RobbieWxyz Yes, it's managed by the browser. For using it, see [here](https://hstspreload.org/). As preload is difficult to reverse, it is important to follow their recommendations.

Comment: HSTS doesn't block self-signed certificates per se. If they are properly installed, you can also use them for HSTS sites.

Comment: @Arminius True, if the certificate is deployed to the browser, there is no warning, so there is nothing to abort and HSTS will allow it (this is defined by the [rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797#page-27)).

Comment: @tim How do we know a website has or using HSTS?

Comment: @Pierrot Just check the HTTP header. For example via `curl -I https://facebook.com/`. It shows `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; preload`, so we know that it uses HSTS (although the preload directive does not follow the requirement to have includeSubDomains set, so it may be excluded from the preload list in the future).